# how to use after in a function with signals vhdl

Tags: function, time, vhdl

i would like to use after in a function because i want not to change the signal Puerta_A1 inmediatly but after some time. my function is like this:

```
function fotocelula(FOT_A,FC_cerradoA,FC_abiertoA,AL_A,AP_A: in std_logic) 
return std_logic_vector is  
variable salida: std_logic_vector;
begin
    IF FOT_A='1' THEN 
      report "hola1";
        if FC_cerradoA='1' THEN
            return "11";
        end if;
        if FC_abiertoA='1' THEN
            return "00";
        end if;
        if AL_A='1' then
            return "11";
        end if;
        if AP_A='1' then
            return "01";
        end if; 
        salida:="10" after 200 ns;
        return salida;
    end if;
    IF FOT_A='0' THEN 
      report "hola2";
        if FC_abiertoA='1' THEN
            return "00";
        end if;
        if AL_A='1' then
            return "11";
        end if;
        if AP_A='1' then
            return "01";
        end if;
        return "01";
    else return "10";
    end if;
end fotocelula;
```

thanks

Comment: Delays are not supported in functions. Moreover, `salida` is not a signal. Variables can not schedule value assignments. Use a procedure to solve your problem.

Comment: delays cannot be synthesized. Except if you're inside a testbench, it's not likely the way to get what you want...